# How to Combine dot(.) that has no spaces thereafter? [Regular Expression]

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

This is my code `[^\.!\?]+[!\?\.]`

I want to separate every sentence perfectly in a post. I am using javascript regex. The problem is when the dot(.) is between characters without spaces so they are separated when they should be merged.

For example:
"*Apa yang terjadi? Aku terkena musibah! Uang saya 90.000 dicuri maling.*"

> Uang saya 90.

and

> 000 dicuri maling.

should merge into

> Uang saya 90.000 dicuri maling.

See attached picture below

[image: Regular Expression Tester]

Comment: Does this work for you? `.+?[?!.](?= |$)`

Comment: @CAustin, Yes, this really works. I am very grateful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even better, you can use the following syntax that will **accept several spaces** and other blank characters after the sentence ending character and the leading blank characters **will not be part** of the string that will be extracted!!!

```
[^\s].+?[?!.](?=\s+|$)
```

**Limitations:**

- for example `10 B.C.` and other abbreviations will be detected as sentence...
- strings like: `terkena musibah!Uang saya 90.000 dicuri maling.` will be detected as one sentence...

**New version:**

I have adapted the regex in the following way, to solve the limitations of the regex proposed so far:

```
[^\s.!?][a-zA-Z@#$%^&,;"':*()-_+=/\\|{}><()[\]\s\d]*?([?!]|((?<=[^A-Z])\.(?=[^0-9])))
```

and I have test it on the following text:

> ```
> Apa ya{ng terjadi? Ak[u +10 B.C. ter,ke]na 10.3 mus}ibah.Uang say\a 90!000 dic&uri ma|ling.
> Apa yang te*r(j)adi? Aku terkena mus%ibah! Uang sa^ya 90.000 dicuri maling.
> ter;ke|na mus-ibah?uang saya 90..000 dicuri m"aling.
> ter@kena mus+ibah!ua=ng say$a 90?000 dicuri ma'ling.
> terk\ena mus#ibah.uang saya 90.000 dicuri maling.
> Apa yang terjadi? Aku 10 B. C. terke\na mu/sibah.Uang saya 90!000 dicuri maling.
> Apa yang terjadi? Aku -10 B. C. terke\na mu/sibah. Uang saya 90!000 dicuri maling.
> ```

**Advantages:**

Abbreviations are preserved: `Ak[u +10 B.C. ter,ke]na 10.3 mus}ibah.` is seen as one sentence, preserving the B.C.

`terkena musibah!Uang saya 90.000 dicuri maling.` would be separated in **two** sentences: `terkena musibah!` **and** `Uang saya 90.000 dicuri maling.`

Good luck!

Comment: [new version] not working in tester https://www.regextester.com/?fam=99639

Comment: I am very interested in regex `[^\s].+?[?!.](?=\s+|$)` but it would be better if 3 digits before dot(.) merged with the sentence afterwards. Example: `10. Ten.` and `100. One hundred.` Look https://www.regextester.com/?fam=99651

Answer (score 2):

Try `([.!?])\s` to create array like the following:

```js
let str =  "Apa yang terjadi? Test test test. Aku terkena musibah! Uang saya 90.000 dicuri maling."
str = str.split(/([.!?])\s/g);
let res = [];
for(let i=0; i <= str.length; i=i+2){
  let x = str.length-1 > i? str[i+1] : '';
  let newstr = str[i] + x;
  res.push(newstr);
}
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work in most occasions.

```
(?=[^ ]|^).+?[?!.](?= |$|\n)
```

Checked here: https://regexr.com/